# How to set an in contract CPU bill time check / how to store the CPU time utilized

Tags: cpu

How can this be achieved?

check ( cpu_billable_time < 500 ), " sorry, this code won't let you spend more than 500 µs in billable time, please try again later");

This is aside from the max_transaction_cpu_usage in the json.

From what I've read, this may not be possible, any other suggestions?
Otherwise, how can my contract save the amount of billed CPU?

Answer (score 1):

there's no way at this moment to achieve what you want: to limit your account to not spend more than 500 µs in billable time.

here's more info related to your question:
[Getting account CPU usage in smart contract](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/getting-account-cpu-usage-in-smart-contract)